# refresh page periodically and programmatically

Tags: angular

I have an angular application for which I would like to refresh the page periodically say everyday at 12PM. To do so, I want to use the `cron` library which in principle should do the job. My cron implementation is the following:

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

const cron: CronJob = new CronJob('* * * * * *', () => {window.location.reload()}, null,true);
cron.start();
```

My problem is where to put that code. If I put it in a component then the cron will be restarted each time the component will be reloaded which should be avoided. The problem will be the same with a service that would be injected in a component. So where can I put my cron so that it is declared just once for all ? Would you have any idea ?

Comment: Why not get the component to automatically refresh itself using the `window.setInterval` function? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: thanks for the hint. However, I do need some kind of cron functionnality to perform the refreshing periodically (in my case every day at 12PM)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend avoiding reloading the entire app every few minutes to avoid the bootstrapping process involved with every reload. Preferably, use a Service to reload the specific components you want to periodically update.

That being said, if you are intent on reloading the entire app with this approach, you can either

- Create an @Injectable() service, making sure to use `provideIn: root`, and have the service injected into the app.component. this will ensure your service is initialized only once.

  - More here on [Angular Services](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services)
  - place your cron logic in the constructor of the service.
- or you can simply place this logic directly in the root app component

Comment: I tried your first approach and it works. Many thanks.